# show a map with the current location of the user and the stations downloaded from the server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

good morning everyone i have a problem with a fragment class. Specifically, I want to show the user's current location and the location of different train stations downloaded from the server.
My code is:

```
public class MapsLine extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
        private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
        private LocationCallback locationCallback;
        private boolean requestingLocationUpdates = true;
        GoogleMap gMap;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
        private String sid_user;
        private int did;
        FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
        Location currentLocation;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps_line, container, false);
                getcurrentlocatiom();
                get_stations();
                return rootView;
        }
        public void get_stations(){
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);  //use SuppoprtMapFragment for using in fragment instead of activity  MapFragment = activity   SupportMapFragment = fragment


                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                                gMap = mMap;

                                if(checkLocationPermission()) {
                                        Log.d("main_activity_spinner","ok sta partendp");

                                }else {

                                        PolylineOptions polyline1 = new PolylineOptions();
                                        List<LatLng> routeArray = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                                        JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
                                        String GET_STATIONS = "https://help.php";
                                        try {
                                                requestParam.put("sid", sid_user);
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(
                                                Request.Method.POST,
                                                GET_STATIONS,
                                                requestParam,
                                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                                try {
                                                                                String name = stations.getString("sname");
                                                                                String lat = stations.getString("lat");
                                                                           
                                                                                        .add(new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lon)));                                                                         polyline1.color(Color.RED);

                                                                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lon));
                                                                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in " + name));
                                                                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                                                                LatLng from_Latlng = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lat), Float.parseFloat(lon));
                                                                                if (!routeArray.contains(latLng)) {
                                                                                        routeArray.add(latLng);
                                                                                }
                                                                        }
                                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                                        return;
                                                                }

                                                                drawLine(routeArray);
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                        }
                                                });
                                        MainActivity.requestQueue.add(req);

                                }}});
        }
        public void drawLine(List<LatLng> points) {
                if (points == null) {
                        Log.e("Draw Line", "got null as parameters");
                        return;
                }

                Polyline line = gMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED));
                line.setPoints(points);
                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");
                sid_user = settings1.getString("sid", "null");
        }


        private void getcurrentlocatiom() {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);  //use SuppoprtMapFragment for using in fragment instead of activity  MapFragment = activity   SupportMapFragment = fragment
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                if (locationResult == null) {
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "location request is null");
                                        return;
                                }
                                get_stations();
                                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                                        Log.d("Location", "New Location received: " + location.toString());
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", String.valueOf(latitude));
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", String.valueOf(longitude));
                                }

                        }


                };
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                //se non voglio ottenere aggiornamenti di posizione in background, mi devo ricordare di sospenderli
                fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                requestingLocationUpdates = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onResume");
                //controllo i permessi di posizione
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Permessi OK");
                        //richiedo l'ultima posizione
                        //richiedo aggiornamenti sulla posizione
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        getcurrentlocatiom();
                }
        }
        public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //ho i permessi, scrivo nella casella di testo che va tutto bene
                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "The permission is granted");
                        return true;
                } else {
                        //non ho i permessi, devo richiederli
                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "Ask for permission");

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        return false;
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        // permission was granted
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "Now the permission is granted");
                                        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
                                        getcurrentlocatiom();
                                        startLocationUpdates();
                                } else {
                                        // permission was not granted
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "Permission still not granted");
                                }
                                break;
                        }
        }
}
        private void startLocationUpdates() {
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {

                        //inizio a chiedere gli aggiornamenti di posizione
                        requestingLocationUpdates = true;
                        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); //in ms.
                        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());

                }
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                gMap = googleMap;
                if(checkLocationPermission()){
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                gMap.clear(); //clear old markers
        }}
}
```

Basically after the user gives the permissions, my application shows the current position of the user, but does not show the positions of the railway stations downloaded from the server (get_stations ()). So I want a map showing the current location of the user and the train stations downloaded from the server ((get_stations ()). Can I show in the map the current location of the user and the train stations downloaded from the server? And what can I do?

Comment: Why you added onMapReady callback twice... Use one callback then onMapReady check permission after fetch location..  fetch stations show result on your map.

Comment: what is the difference between callback and onMapReady? are they the same?

Comment: OnMapReadyCallback()  interface having that method... You implemented on top class itself then why again added in the get station method... You have understand map and flow your business...

Comment: Currently getStation method you used.. so remove class implements...

Comment: and don't call move camera.. when the loop execution won't work... Set zoom level to the current location that's better.